# pyMongo remove / modify found documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Writing a function that finds documents and if "delete == True" then delete them.

Is there a way to delete documents which are the result of ".find" operation?

```
    def findOrphanSensors(self, delete = False):
       deviceList = sorted(self._dbC.devicesCol.find({}).distinct('_id'))
       print(deviceList)
       orphanSensors = self._dbC.sensorsCol.find({'parentDeviceID':{'$nin':deviceList}})
       print(orphanSensors.count())
       if delete == True:
          orphanSensors.remove() ???
```

I can do:

```
    if delete == True:
        self._dbC.sensorsCol.deleteMany({'parentDeviceID': {'$nin': deviceList}})
```

but I would think that if I already have the search result in "orphanSensors" then there is no need to redo the search...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The result of a `find` may be iterated.

```py
for orphan in orphanSensors:
  self._dbC.sensorsCol.deleteOne(orphan['_id'])
```

However, this may not be as efficient as calling `delete_many()`. If you don't need to print the number of orphans before you delete them, then you could rearrange you code like this:

```py
def findOrphanSensors(self, delete = False):
  deviceList = sorted(self._dbC.devicesCol.distinct('_id'))
  print(deviceList)
  orphan_filter = {'parentDeviceID':{'$nin':deviceList}}
  if delete:
    result = self._dbC.sensorsCol.delete_many(orphan_filter)
    print(result.deleted_count)
  else:
    result = self._dbC.sensorsCol.find(orphanFilter)
    print(result.count())
```